# Почему при изменении шрифта ПОСЛЕ изменения ширины, сбрасывается ширина?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, vcl

Делаю так:

```
  Label2.Font.Color := $ff0000;
  Label2.Width := 900;
```

Синий текст в lable шириной 900px; (всё верно.)

Но стоит сделать так:

```
  Label2.Width := 900;
  Label2.Font.Color := $ff0000;
```

Синий текст в lable при этом сохраняется, но ширина ломается до начального 31px (или в размер одного целогого слова, если оно больше 31px)
Почему такое происходит?

Comment: я давно делфи не трогал, то там вроде было свойство типа autosize, которое подганяло размер компонента под внутренности. Изменение цвета как раз и приведет к пересчету размера.

Comment: @KoVadim, Спасибо. Так и есть. Вот и я не трогал лет 8-10, а тут решил, и, понимаю, что мозг уже не тот, что был в 25-30 лет! Он не хочет лезть и ковырять-проверять все кнопочки и настройки, как это было раньше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У TLabel есть флаг `AutoSize`, выставление которого делает автоматическую подгонку размера контрола под размер текста.

Теперь давайте смотреть: при изменении свойства шрифта (`Font.Color`), у него вызывается метод `Changed` который сигнализирует владельцу, что произошло изменение, а при таком сигнале об изменении шрифта и наличии флага `AutoSize`, происходит пересчет размера контрола, что и сбрасывает вам ширину.

Правильное ли это поведение - не совсем. По идее изменение параметров не влияющих на размер текста (таких как цвет), не должно вызывать пересчет размера. А изменение размера контрола при выставленном флаге `AutoSize` должно игнорироваться.

Решение - если вы сами выставляете ширину - поставьте флаг `Label2.AutoSize := false`

Answer (score 1):

Просто, если свойство `AutoSize = true` (по умолчанию это так), то изменение содержимого приводит к повторному расчёту размера и его автоматической установке.

Поэтому, либо используйте первый вариант, либо устанавливайте `AutoSize = false`.